# Method resolution order (__mro__) not available in Python3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder about that it seems like that the method resolution order attribute **mro** is not available in Python 3.x anymore. Using Python 3.5.2 and creating a random class object instance A, built-in or self-implemented, for example

```
A = dict()
```

and then calling

```
A.__mro__
```

doesnt work, raising

```
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__mro__'
```

I tried to use A.mro(), but this gives the same type of exception.
How do I receive the method resolution order now?

Comment: Try `object.mro()`.

Comment: What is `A` at all? and how you defined it?

Comment: Answer given below by Antti solved it. I will edit the question anyway to make it clear that I was talking about A as an instance of a class object

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That doesn't work on *instances*. The error hints that the variable `A` in question is not bound to a type, but to an *instance* of class `A`. types (classes) very much do have `__mro__`:

```
>>> int.__mro__
(<class 'int'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> class Foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> Foo.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Since `A` is an instance of a type and not the type itself, you can use `type(A).__mro__`.

Additionally, your code wouldn't have worked in Python 2 either; no, instances didn't have `__mro__` there either.

Comment: Thanks, the instance hint nailed it! I wasnt aware of that. I will mark this as the answer

Comment: @joaquinn If `A` is an instance of a custom object you can access to the class `mro` by `A.__class__.__mro__` or `type(f).__mro__`.